# Regex to allow character and two operators

Tags: regex

I aw trying to write a regular expression that allows only 3 or 4 alphanumeric and will also allow % and *, which can be used with the alphabets.

ex: abc* or abc% some thing like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9*%]{4,5}$
```

**Regex Explanation:**

```
^                - Line start
[a-zA-Z0-9*%]    - Alphanumeric (letters or digits) OR * OR %
{4,5}            - 4 or 5 of those
$                - Line end
```

Comment: The * and % should be an optional field, the user require, they will go for it. can you give for that also

Comment: Actually `[a-zA-Z0-9*%]` does make `*` OR `%` optional.